# No Forms displayed in Forms Dashboard in Sitecore 10.3 with The required anti-forgery cookie error

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 10.3. I have seen no Forms after I created some in Forms Dashboard in Forms Builder.

I did rebuild of indexes after which they appeared but then they disappeared again. I suspect that it's due to missing language selector and also publishing targets:
[image]

I can see these in network tab:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Same for languages request:
[image]

Comment: Does it work in incognito mode?

Comment: Go to Desktop mode, and switch to Master if you are not on Master DB. Come back to Forms Builder and check again.

Comment: @MarekMusielak yes it is working in Incognito. I have cleared the cache in Normal window and it's working also there. What has happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue twice already. Both times it was related to cookies.

First time it was an SXA site which included space character in it's name. As a result it used cookie called like `sxa site name#lang` and spaces in cookie name are not allowed ( https://curl.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html ) so it broke lot of functionality in Sitecore backend, starting from Forms, through Experience Analytics, Experience Profile and Marketing Automation.

Second time it was custom Matomo tracking script added on CM servers as well. It again resulted in incorrect cookie values and again, Sitecore backend wasn't working properly.

If forms do work for you in incognito mode, it may be related to cookies for you. Just open dev tools in your browser and try clearing suspected cookies.